# Constructing Cayley Graphs in SageMath

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, group-theory, sagemath, cayley-graphs

I am having confusions in constructing a Cayley Graph in Sage Math. Say, I want to construct the Cayley graph on the Symmetric Group $S_4$ with respect to the generating set consisting of all transpositions, what code do I use.

I tried the following minimal code:

```
CG = G.cayley_graph(generators = [PermutationGroupElement([1,2]),PermutationGroupElement([1,3]),PermutationGroupElement([1,4]),PermutationGroupElement([2,3]),PermutationGroupElement([2,4]),PermutationGroupElement([3,4])])
CGU = CG.to_undirected()
CGU.show()
```

But, I get the error

```
    502         if not is_valid_permutation(self.perm, self.n):
--> 503             raise ValueError("invalid data to initialize a permutation")
    504 
    505         # This is more expensive

ValueError: invalid data to initialize a permutation
```

How do I rectify the code so as to produce my desired Cayley Graph. Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Have you seen this : https://ask.sagemath.org/question/46450/constructing-graphs-using-permutation-or-symmetric-groups/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had success with the following:

```
G=SymmetricGroup(4)
CG = G.cayley_graph(generators=[G((1,2)),G((1,3)),G((1,4)),G((2,3)),G((2,4)),G((3,4))])
CGU = CG.to_undirected()
CGU.show()
```

Comment: I think you could help me in [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4434291/checking-for-indopenedent-sets-in-a-bipartite-graph-with-equal-number-of-odd-and) question of mine