# Checking for indepenedent sets in a bipartite graph with equal number of odd and even elements in SageMath

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, discrete-mathematics, sagemath, cayley-graphs

By using the IndependentSets module in SageMath, we can list all the independent sets of a graph. Suppose I have a bipartite graph on the Symmetric Group with partite sets consisting of even and odd permutations.

How do I enumerate and list out all those independent sets which consists of equal number of elements from even and odd permutations. What all methods and functions do I need to use. Is there some built in function  for listing the type of a symmetric group element as even or odd.

My idea of pseudo-code idea would be:

```
G=SymmetricGroup(4)
CG = G.cayley_graph(generators=[G((1,2)),G((1,3)),G((1,4)),G((2,3)),G((2,4)),G((3,4))])
CGU = CG.to_undirected()
I=IndependentSets(CGU)
for list in I:
   for i in list:
       if enumerate(type(list[i])=='even')==enumerate(type(list[i]=='odd'):
add list in list1

print(list1)
```

However, I encountered the error that list indices must be integers or slices and not permutation group elements. How do rectify this? Any hints?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
from sage.graphs.independent_sets import IndependentSets
S = SymmetricGroup(3) # Or whatever you want.
P1 = [S((1, 2)), S((1, 3)), S((2, 3))] # Two parts of the partition,
P2 = [S((1,2,3)), S((1,3,2)), S(())]   # adjust these as you want.
G = BipartiteGraph([P1,P2])
I = IndependentSets(G)
L = []
for l in I:
    if (sum(x.sign()==1 for x in l) == sum(x.sign()==-1 for x in l)):
        L.append(l)
print(L)
```

or slightly more efficiently, replace the third last line with

```
    if (sum(x.sign() for x in l) == 0):
```

Comment: sorry, when I perform the above code with the bipartite graph generated from a cayley graph, the error reads as ;AttributeError: 'SymmetricGroup_with_category' object has no attribute 'edge_iterator'

Comment: @vidyarthi Weird. It works with my installation. Perhaps you need to update SageMath? On which step does it fail?

Comment: @vidyarthi Wait, did you try the code as written in my answer first, or did you modify it for your specific example? Try the above, verbatim, first. You may need to `reset()` Sage first. If this works, but your modification does not, then you'll have to put more detail in your question.

Comment: Yet another sagemath question from my side, [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4436597/construction-of-total-graph-using-sagemath). Hope you can do it this time too

Comment: @vidyarthi I don't think I will be able to help, sorry. I'm not actually an expert on Sage, Python, or even graph or group theory. I've been using your questions as an excuse to learn some new things, but at the moment, I just don't have the time.