# Construction of total graph using SageMath

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, sagemath

Let $G$ be a graph of order $n$ and size $e$. The total graph $T$ is the graph associated to $G$, which consists of order $n+e$ and edges consist of the union of the edges of $G$, the edges of line graph of $G$ and the edges of the subdivision graph of $G$.

I know that there is the line_graph() module in SageMath. But, I am unaware of the any module for subdivision graph. In addition, how do we form a disjoint union of edges of the three graphs $G$, its line and subdivision graphs, when their vertex sets are different. So finally, how can we construct the total graph $T$ in SageMath. Any hints? Thanks beforehand.

Comment: Could you provide us with the definition of the subdivision graph of $G$? As far as I know, it is any graph that is obtained from $G$ by ANY sequence of edge subdivisions.

Comment: @DavidScholz Yes, the subdivision graph is the graph obtained by subdividing each edge of the graph, that is, replacing each edge in the graph by a vertex connected by two new edges to the incident vertices of the original edge in the graph

Comment: @DavidScholz Another equivalent definition of total graph is [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Total_coloring)

Comment: @vidyarthi At this point, you might not care, but in general you want to add such information to your question - not in comments as an afterthought. The definition of "subdivision graph" is much more obscure than the definition of the line graph, and if I were asking a question, I'd even consider defining the line graph for completeness.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By using the equivalent definition of total graph as the square(or distance-2 graph) of the subdivision graph(the graph formed by subdividing each edge, we obtain the following pseudo-code:

```
g = Any_desired_graph

k = 1
g.subdivide_edges(g.edges(), k)
h=g.distance_graph(list(range(1,3)))
h.plot()
```

We can replace the `Any_desired_graph` by our graph whose total graph is required.